# NSURLConnection and Basic HTTP Authentication in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I need to invoke an initial `GET HTTP request` with Basic `Authentication`. This would be the first time the request is sent to the server and I already have the `username & password` so there's no need for a challenge from the server for authorization.

First question:

1. Does `NSURLConnection` have to be set as synchronous to do Basic Auth? According to the answer on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993409/basic-http-authentication-on-iphone), it seems that you can't do Basic Auth if you opt for the async route.
2. Anyone know of any some sample code that illustrates Basic Auth on a `GET request` without the need for a challenge response? [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) shows an example but only after the server has issued the challenge request to the client.

I'm kind of new the networking portion of the SDK and I'm not sure which of the other classes I should use to get this working. (I see the `NSURLCredential` class but it seems that it is used only with `NSURLAuthenticationChallenge` after the client has requested for an authorized resource from the server).

Answer (score 132, accepted):

I'm using an asynchronous connection with [MGTwitterEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa) and it sets the authorization in the `NSMutableURLRequest` (`theRequest`) like so:

```
NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", [self username], [self password]];
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodingWithLineLength:80]];
[theRequest setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

I don't believe this method requires going through the challenge loop but I could be wrong

Comment: Should have noted that I'm doing so in an OS X app and not an iPhone App, but hopefully it will still work for you

Comment: Can you tell me what's the reason behind limiting the encoding line length to 80 in your example code? I thought that HTTP headers have a max length of something like 4k (or maybe some servers don't take anything longer than that).

Comment: I didn't write that part, it's just part of MGTwitterEngine, from a category added to NSData.  See NSData+Base64.h/m here: http://github.com/ctshryock/MGTwitterEngine

Comment: For base64-encoding (`[authData base64EncodedString]`) add the NSData+Base64.h and .m File from Matt Gallagher to your XCode-Project ([Base64 encoding options on the Mac and iPhone](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html)).

Comment: If you don't explicitly stop disk caching (and your server doesn't stop it with a `Cache-Control` header), this method can cause your request to be cached in `Cache.db`, which means your password will be accessible on disk.

Comment: NSASCIIStringEncoding will corrupt non-usascii usernames or passwords. Use NSUTF8StringEncoding instead

Comment: base64EncodingWithLineLength does not exist in the year 2014 on NSData.  Use base64Encoding instead.

Comment: @bickster `base64Encoding`is deprecated since iOS 7.0 and OS X 10.9. I use `[authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed]` instead. Also available are ` NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength` or `NSDataBase64Encoding76CharacterLineLength`

Comment: You should not do that.  Apple's docs say that it won't work, and it definitely has failed in many versions of iOS over the years, because the Authorization header is explicitly reserved for use by the URL loading system, and cannot safely be set in requests.

Answer (score 80):

Even the question is answered, I want to present the solution, which doesn't require external libs, I found in another thread:

```
// Setup NSURLConnection
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL
                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                     timeoutInterval:30.0];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
[connection release];

// NSURLConnection Delegates
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"received authentication challenge");
        NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"USER"
                                                                    password:@"PASSWORD"
                                                                 persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
        NSLog(@"credential created");
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        NSLog(@"responded to authentication challenge");    
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"previous authentication failure");
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    ...
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    ...
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    ...
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is not quite the same as the other solutions: this contacts the server first, receives a 401 response, then responds with the correct credentials. So you're wasting a round-trip. On the upside, your code will handle other challenges, such as HTTP Digest Auth. It's a trade-off.

Comment: Anyway, this is the "correct way" of doing it. All the other ways is a shortcut.

Comment: @dom I've used this but for some reason didRecieveAuthenticationChallenge is not being called and I'm getting a 403 access denied message back from the site. Anyone know what's gone amiss?

Comment: Yes, this is the only correct way to do it.  And it only causes a 401 response the first time.  Subsequent requests to that same server are sent with authentication.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a detailed answer with no 3rd party involved:

Please check here:

```
//username and password value
NSString *username = @“your_username”;
NSString *password = @“your_password”;

//HTTP Basic Authentication
NSString *authenticationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", username, password]];
NSData *authenticationData = [authenticationString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *authenticationValue = [authenticationData base64Encoding];

//Set up your request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.your-api.com/“]];

// Set your user login credentials
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", authenticationValue] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

// Send your request asynchronously
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *responseCode, NSData *responseData, NSError *responseError) {
      if ([responseData length] > 0 && responseError == nil){
            //logic here
      }else if ([responseData length] == 0 && responseError == nil){
             NSLog(@"data error: %@", responseError);
             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Error accessing the data" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alert show];
             [alert release];
      }else if (responseError != nil && responseError.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut){
             NSLog(@"data timeout: %@”, NSURLErrorTimedOut);
             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"connection timeout" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alert show];
             [alert release];
      }else if (responseError != nil){
             NSLog(@"data download error: %@”,responseError);
             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"data download error" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alert show];
             [alert release];
      }
}]
```

Kindly let me know your feedback on this.

Thanks

Comment: The method base64Encoding you are using to convert NSData to NSString is now deprecated: 
```- (NSString *)base64Encoding NS_DEPRECATED(10_6, 10_9, 4_0, 7_0);```
Better to use NSDataBase64Encoding category instead.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to import the whole of MGTwitterEngine and you aren't doing an asynchronous request 
Then you can use 
http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/basic_authentication_iphone_cocoa_touch

To base64 encode the Username and password
So replace

```
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodingWithLineLength:80]];
```

with

```
NSString *encodedLoginData = [Base64 encode:[loginString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

after

you will need to include the following file

```
static char *alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

@implementation Base64
+(NSString *)encode:(NSData *)plainText {
    int encodedLength = (((([plainText length] % 3) + [plainText length]) / 3) * 4) + 1;
    unsigned char *outputBuffer = malloc(encodedLength);
    unsigned char *inputBuffer = (unsigned char *)[plainText bytes];

    NSInteger i;
    NSInteger j = 0;
    int remain;

    for(i = 0; i < [plainText length]; i += 3) {
        remain = [plainText length] - i;

        outputBuffer[j++] = alphabet[(inputBuffer[i] & 0xFC) >> 2];
        outputBuffer[j++] = alphabet[((inputBuffer[i] & 0x03) << 4) | 
                                     ((remain > 1) ? ((inputBuffer[i + 1] & 0xF0) >> 4): 0)];

        if(remain > 1)
            outputBuffer[j++] = alphabet[((inputBuffer[i + 1] & 0x0F) << 2)
                                         | ((remain > 2) ? ((inputBuffer[i + 2] & 0xC0) >> 6) : 0)];
        else 
            outputBuffer[j++] = '=';

        if(remain > 2)
            outputBuffer[j++] = alphabet[inputBuffer[i + 2] & 0x3F];
        else
            outputBuffer[j++] = '=';            
    }

    outputBuffer[j] = 0;

    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithCString:outputBuffer length:strlen(outputBuffer)];
    free(outputBuffer);

    return result;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 3):

Since NSData::dataUsingEncoding is deprecated (ios 7.0), you could use this solution:

```
// Forming string with credentials 'myusername:mypassword'
NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", username, password];
// Getting data from it
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
// Encoding data with base64 and converting back to NSString
NSString* authStrData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[authData base64EncodedDataWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
// Forming Basic Authorization string Header
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", authStrData];
// Assigning it to request
[request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [GTMHTTPFetcher](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-http-fetcher/) for your connection, basic authentication is fairly easy as well. You simply need to provide the credential to the fetcher before beginning the fetch.

```
NSString * urlString = @"http://www.testurl.com/";
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSURLCredential * credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"username" password:@"password" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

GTMHTTPFetcher * gFetcher = [GTMHTTPFetcher fetcherWithRequest:request];
gFetcher.credential = credential;

[gFetcher beginFetchWithDelegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(fetchCompleted:withData:andError:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can you tell me what's the reason behind limiting the encoding line length to 80 in your example code? I thought that HTTP headers have a max length of something like 4k (or maybe some servers don't take anything longer than that). – Justin Galzic Dec 29 '09 at 17:29

It is not limiting to 80, it is an option of the method base64EncodingWithLineLength in NSData+Base64.h/m, where you can split your encoded string into multiple lines, which is useful for other application, such as nntp transmission. I believe 80 is chosen by the twitter engine author to be a length big enough to accommodate most user/password encoded result to one line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AFNetworking](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/3.1.0/) (it is opensource), here is code that worked for me. This code sends file with basic authentication. Just change url, email and password.

```
NSString *serverUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.yoursite.com/uploadlink", profile.host];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:serverUrl parameters:nil error:nil];


NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

// Forming string with credentials 'myusername:mypassword'
NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", email, emailPassword];
// Getting data from it
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
// Encoding data with base64 and converting back to NSString
NSString* authStrData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[authData base64EncodedDataWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
// Forming Basic Authorization string Header
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", authStrData];
// Assigning it to request
[request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[url path]];
NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:filePath progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
// This is not called back on the main queue.
// You are responsible for dispatching to the main queue for UI updates
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //Update the progress view
                LLog(@"progres increase... %@ , fraction: %f", uploadProgress.debugDescription, uploadProgress.fractionCompleted);
            });
        } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Success: %@ %@", response, responseObject);
            }
        }];
[uploadTask resume];
```