# NSURLErrorDomain error -1012

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, nsurlcredential

I need to parse a xml file from a password protected URL I tried the following

```
NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"admin"  password:@"123456" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc]
                                         initWithHost:@"xyz.com"
                                         port:80
                                         protocol:@"http"
                                         realm:nil
                                         authenticationMethod:NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault];  
[[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] setCredential:credential
                                             forProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];    
url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse: &response error: &error];   
 NSString *dataStr=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
 NSLog(@"data == %@\n error in connecting == %@",dataStr,error);
```

I got the following response

```
data == <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>401 Authorization Required</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Authorization Required</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 401 Authorization Required
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

error in connecting == Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x6e51b90 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://example.com/api/ID/password/xml/,

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: I think you are looking for http authentication: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973325/nsurlconnection-and-basic-http-authentication

Comment: I am also facing the same issue when authenticating the credentials. But, this happens only for second time validation, first time login works and signout and login fails.

Comment: please post the solution if u resolved

Comment: Check if the NSURLProtectionSpace you get from the server is the same one you provide to NSURLCredentialStorage. The server probably has something set for the realm.

Comment: Are you using a proxy? I had the same issue with a proxy

Answer (score 6):

While using a `NSURLRequest` to access a server, the delegate methods of `NSURLConnection` provides a *way to be notified* when an *authentication is challenged*.

This below sample will show one approach to handle URLs that asks credentials.

```
- (void)CallPasswordProtectedWebService
{
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your url"];
 NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
}

//when server asks the credentials this event will fire

 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
  didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{

 if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
    NSURLCredential *newCredential;
    newCredential=[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"username"                                               password:@"password"                                              persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential
           forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
} else {
    [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
}

//when connection succeeds this event fires

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
 NSLog(@"Successfuly connected ");  

}

//when connection fails the below event fires 

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 NSLog(@"connection failed");

}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

In my case the **issue was caused by a firewall/proxy requiring a client certificate for all HTTPS calls**. I resolved this issue by providing a NSURLProtocol subclass to handle authentication challenges and provide this certificate.

```
[NSURLProtocol registerClass:self];

//implement these methods
- (void)didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;

- (void)resolveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge withCredential:(NSURLCredential *)credential;
```

Answer (score 0):

With Xcode 6, my app would not download a large number of files on IOS 8 platforms eventhough it worked fine on earlier IOS.  My code was essentially as you have it below, but the error kept appearing when an authentication challenge came.

I had to change the code to

```
 if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
    NSURLCredential *newCredential;
    newCredential=[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"username"                                               password:@"password"                                              persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential
           forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
} else {
   NSURLCredential *newCredential;
    newCredential=[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"username"                                               password:@"password"                                              persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential
           forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Which of course makes the IF statement superfluous (it can be removed).  I have no explanation but without responding to the challenge with username and password even on a persistent session causes an error (-1012).  Now it works as on the earlier IOS