# STTwitterAPI oauth login

Tags: ios, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, sttwitter

I am trying to use STTwitter to post a tweet from my iOS app.

However when I try to login to the API using

```
self.twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIWithOAuthConsumerKey:_consumerKeyTextField.text consumerSecret:_consumerSecretTextField.text username:@"username" password:@"password"];
```

I get "Unhandled authentication challenge type - NSURLAuthenticationMethodOAuth" and "The operation couldn't be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error - 1012)"

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14362651/740474

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and I have answer yet :S If it's XAuth problem that the error is misleading.

Comment: You're right, the error should be more clear. I'm going to improve this point.

Answer (score 1):

Your tokens are not XAuth enabled.

See STTwitter's README: https://github.com/nst/STTwitter#xauth

Comment: This doesn't seem correct. Note the error returned in the case you refer has `2` in the end.

Comment: OAuth or OAuth2, you should ensure that your tokens are XAuth enabled.