# iOS: How can I add credentials to my code for my NSURL?

Tags: asp.net, ios, vb.net, ios6, nsurl

I'm trying to access a page that has xml I'm trying to parse. I'm using the following code which works as long as I do not need credentials. How can I add credentials to this code?

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:URLPath];
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

[xmlParser setDelegate: self];
success = [xmlParser parse];
```

Above my "URLPath" is my url string.  I've tried using the following url path format but it doesn't work for me.  `http://username:password@mypage.com/path/to/file.aspx?Function=Update`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `NSURLConnectionDelegates`

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"received authentication challenge");
        NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"USER"
                                                                    password:@"PASSWORD"
                                                                 persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
        NSLog(@"credential created");
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        NSLog(@"responded to authentication challenge");    
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"previous authentication failure");
    }
}
```

See [NSURLConnection and Basic HTTP Authentication in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973325/nsurlconnection-and-basic-http-authentication) for more information

Comment: Can I use NSURLConnection with NSURL ?

Comment: @daveomcd no NSURLConnection is a different class. I would recommend NSURLConnection since it has more options and can be used async.

Comment: Alright thanks... I suppose I'll try and adapt the code to NSURLConnection.