# Authentication for NSURLConnection when it is not required

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to download a file from google trends. I'm using NSURLConnection to get the file.

I want to let google know I'm logged in (ie authenticate the connection) in order to have no download limit. I tried using:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```

The problem is since the login is **not required**, the method is never being called. Is there a way I can make sure the connection is authenticated? Thx!

Note: I asked this question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661960/authentication-for-nsurlconnection-when-it-is-not-required), but I didn't get a reply so I'm asking again - hope that's ok

**EDIT:** Maybe I can use `- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse` ? Can I somehow authenticate through the cache?

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the correct header fields of the `NSURLRequest`. Take a look at the answer of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973325/nsurlconnection-and-basic-http-authentication). You will have to look for [base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk) encoding too.