# bigcommerce api on iphone

Tags: iphone

i am using bigcommerce api in iphone to fetch data from that so i am  doing it with the help of xml parsing but to get the list of orders it is asking for the login into bigcommerce website and then parse the data if anyone help me in this then i will be very thankful , please tell me through xml parsing how we can send login credentials and then hit on the url to parse data.....

thankyou

i am writing this code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
// Add the navigation controller's view to the window and display.
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

// Override point for customization after application launch.
NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.labradorhometraining.com/api/v2"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string]];

//    NSString *dataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"screenName\":\"%@\",\"password\":\"%@\",\"pushToken\":\"%@\",\"deviceType\":\"%@\"}", Screentxtf.text,passtxtf.text,  str, deviceType];

[request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
[request appendPostData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=
 [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/xml"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Authorization: Basic ZGVtb2tleTpkZW1vdG9rZW4= " value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",@"api", @"c275ab4076f87"]];
[request setUseSessionPersistence:NO];
[request setUseCookiePersistence:NO];
[request setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICacheForSessionDurationCacheStoragePolicy];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
return YES;
}
```

and this is in root view controller

```
-(void)gototselect{
NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.labradorhometraining.com/api/v2/orders.xml"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string]];

//    NSString *dataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"screenName\":\"%@\",\"password\":\"%@\",\"pushToken\":\"%@\",\"deviceType\":\"%@\"}", Screentxtf.text,passtxtf.text,  str, deviceType];

[request setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];
//    [request appendPostData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",@"api", @"c2714076f87"]];
[request allowCompressedResponse];
[request setUseSessionPersistence:NO];
[request setUseCookiePersistence:NO];
[request setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICacheForSessionDurationCacheStoragePolicy];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any idea about ASIHTTPRequest API and also i never used it my career. But using plain objective-C i share some code for how do you authenticate http request,

```
// Setup NSURLConnection
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL
                                     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                 timeoutInterval:30.0];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
[connection release];

// NSURLConnection Delegates
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"received authentication challenge");
    NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"USER"
                                                                password:@"PASSWORD"
                                                             persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    NSLog(@"credential created");
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    NSLog(@"responded to authentication challenge");    
}
else {
    NSLog(@"previous authentication failure");
}
}

 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse  *)response {
...
}

 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
...
}

 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
...
 }

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
...
}
```

the above code i copied from [NSURLConnection and Basic HTTP Authentication in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973325/nsurlconnection-and-basic-http-authentication) this link.
Also i want to share some more link with you. Refer apple doc for HTTP request http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html
And this post http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/12/nsurlconnection-with-self-signed-certificates/ .. you will get lot of information and tactics about this work.

Comment: @Priyanka, sorry i can't give you my email id but you can meet me here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/iphone-ipad

Comment: @Priyanka, you can chat with me on given link.