# Curl, Asana & ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, curl, asana

I am looking at building a simple cocoa app to create projects in the collaborative app Asana.

I need to make a curl request but I am unsure of how to tackle it.

Example(https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/projects):

```
curl -u <api_key>: https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects -d "name=Things to Buy" -d "notes=These are things we want to purchase." -d "workspace=14916"
```

Any ideas of how I can run or mimic a "curl -u" command?

Thanks!

Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-u/--user` option stands for [Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). It basically adds a `Authorization` HTTP header to the request, with the username/password encoded in base64, e.g `Authorization: Basic Zm9vOmJhcg==`.

Basic auth is precisely one of the authentication scheme supported by the Asana API:

> The Asana API supports two separate authentication schemes: OAuth 2.0 and HTTP Basic Authentication using API keys.

In practice, and according to the [Asana docs](http://developers.asana.com/documentation/#Authentication), the clients should pass:

> the API key as the username, and an empty password

So If you want to perform such a request in plain Objective-C e.g with [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) all you need to do is create this `Authorization` header yourself, taking care to use an empty password. You should be able to do this easily (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1974566/1688185)):

```
NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:", apiKey];
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodingWithLineLength:80]];
[request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Note: base64 encoding is achieved via an `NSData`category such as [this one](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine/blob/master/NSData+Base64.h).

Comment: thanks for your help! Any tips on how would I go about passing variables like I would with curl: curl -u myapiKey12345: https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects -d "name=Test Job" -d "notes=Test blah." -d "workspace=11234456789" -d "team=12345466778"

Comment: @adamteale if it worked, you should upvote and accept his answer ;-) Thanks @deltheil!