# How to get JSON data from server with username and password in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, authentication, passwords

I would like to connect to a server and get back JSON data in iOS. It requires a username and password to access. If I were to grab it with cURL it would look like this:

```
curl -i --user "John@smith.net:password" http://example.com:9999/api/v1.0/users/
```

How do I connect to it in iOS? How can I then print the data (NSLog)?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question: [NSURLConnection and Basic HTTP Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973325/nsurlconnection-and-basic-http-authentication)

After you can print the JSON data using NSLog or process it with library like [SBJson](http://superloopy.io/json-framework/)

Comment: I have attempted to implement it as per the second answer on that link (with 45 points) and nothing is happening. Would it be possible to get a simple complete example on how to do this from you?

Comment: Try at least to debug the code and find out why it is not working. You have there also other working solutions.