# Django REST Framework API call using IOS

Tags: ios, django, api, django-rest-framework

I have built a simple Django application and exposed some API endpoints with Django REST Framework. I am using basic auth for now. I have tested on the command line and all works perfectly:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/json; indent=4' -u myuser:mypass http://myapp.herokuapp.com/items/
```

I am handing the API to an IOS developer. What would be the correct parameters to call in the IOS application to properly authenticate and deliver the JSON data? I am really not familiar with IOS development so I am at a loss as to how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our IOS dev actually used a slightly different implementation, and I'm posting his code for completeness.

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:[NSString stringWithFornat:@"Basic %@",      [ASIHTTPRequest base64forData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@",username,password] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]]];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
[request start];
```

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest hasn't been worked on since 2011 and is as good as deprecated: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Answer (score 2):

When you use 'curl' and use the '-u myuser:mypass' you are sending the username and password in the HTTP Authorization header. I'm not sure how to do this in IOS specifically, but I would try doing a POST request with a url like: http://username:password@example.com/

Comment: Ya, just post to the url.  I'd suggest using MKNetworkKit for an ios networking library.  No reason to try to write your own.

Comment: @M1Reeder `NSURLConnection` can handle basic authentication "almost" automatically - or it can be easily tailored for the applications need in corresponding delegate methods. A developer having experience with networking should be able to accomplish this. Since the web service is REST, one cannot arbitrarily fake the HTTP methods. The POST method is used for a "create resource" request only (PATCH for update). Using https is also mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

Just give the developer the API URLs, username and password and tell him to do basic authentication, he will know what to do.

If he doesn't know what to do, you can point him to this thread: [NSURLConnection and Basic HTTP Authentication in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973325/nsurlconnection-and-basic-http-authentication)

About JSON, I think you can ask the iOS developer to add to request header `'Accept: application/json;'` then it should be fine too.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the authentication problem in this way.

```
let authStr:NSString = "username:password"
let authData:NSData = authStr.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
let authValue:NSString = "Basic \(authData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength))"
request.setValue(authValue, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```