# how to send push from iphone via urban airship?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, push, urbanairship.com

I have an urban airship account and my iOS app ist already configured with the system. My device token is on the server and if I send a test notification from the server I get the notification on my iphone.
BUT how can I send a message FROM my iphone to another user?
I haven't found any stuff about sending through iphone.
This is my code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSDictionary *push;
push = @{@"aps":@{@"alert":@"How are you?"},@"device_tokens":@[@"87892382J393FS77789S90909N82022312332"]};
```

and then I have to send it as json or something else???

Answer (score 0):

As documentation on http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/api/v3/intro.html says, requests are http ones with JSON body.

You need to authorize first. From documentation:

> The username portion is the application key. The password portion is
>   either the application secret, or master secret.

You can find in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973325/nsurlconnection-and-basic-http-authentication) how to authorize on iOS:

```
NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", [self username], [self password]];
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodingWithLineLength:80]];
[request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

And then I guess you should do like this:

```
#import "JSONKit.h"

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/"]];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSDictionary *push = @{@"aps":@{@"alert":@"How are you?"},@"device_tokens":@[@"87892382J393FS77789S90909N82022312332"]};
request.HTTPBody = [push.JSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

Note that you need JSONKit to serialize your dictionary into string

Answer (score 0):

OK this is my actually Method:

```
- (IBAction)sendPush:(id)sender {
NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"app key:app secret"];
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedDataWithOptions:nil]];
[request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

NSDictionary *push = @{@"aps":@{@"alert":@"How are you?"},@"device_tokens":@[@"87892382J393FS77789S90909N82022312332"]};
request.HTTPBody = [push.JSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"push: %@",push);
NSLog(@"request: %@",request);
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
}
```

If I comment the line 6-10 out then I get for the NSLog:

```
2013-11-06 12:59:13.238 myApp[7273:907] push: {
aps =     {
    alert = "How are you?";
};
"device_tokens" =     (
    87892382J393FS77789S90909N82022312332
);
}
2013-11-06 12:59:13.241 myApp[7273:907] request: <NSMutableURLRequest https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/>
```

I really don't know why it doesn't works!!!

Comment: you are doing wrong authorization, you need to send first request with username and pass, get response with OK status, then send another request to `api/push`. Also, you should update question if you get additional info, not to write an answer

Comment: well, now I'm not sure, maybe, you can authorize like this. Anyway, log the server response `NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:nil error:nil];
 NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: -[UAUserAPIClient updateDeviceToken:forUsername:onSuccess:onFailure:] Updating device token.
-[UADeviceAPIClient registerWithData:onSuccess:onFailure:forcefully: Running device registration.
-[UAUser updateDefaultDeviceToken]_block_invoke Device token updated to:<deviceToken>
-[UAPush updateRegistrationForcefully:]_block_invoke Device token registered on Urban Airship successfully.
+[UAKeychainUtils getDeviceID] Retrieved device id info from keychain.
+[UAKeychainUtils getDeviceID] Loaded Device ID:myID
+[UAKeychainUtils getDeviceID] Loaded Model Name:iPhone3,1

Comment: this is not the server response. You are sending a request to the Urban Airship server, it should give you response (in my code it's response string)

Comment: sorry but I really don't get it. Is there a good tutorial or example?

Comment: but efor the request I need an address but I have NO address!!!!!! It is so frustrated to search for days in the internet for a solution but just find nothing.

Comment: well, it's always like this - no one will help you except yourself :) but why `https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/` is not an address?

Comment: What is this for an error? `Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x1cd7e270 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/, NSUnderlyingError=0x1cd7ed20 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)"}`

Comment: i have no idea, try googling it

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, doing this would present a risk in a publicly released app.

Any push through UA requires your master secret to authenticate. If you added your master secret to the app, it would be viewable to a savvy hacker, who could then use it to send unauthorized pushes on your behalf. It has happened to people before.

It's not generally recommended.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Example using the API V3

```
-(void)richPushNotification{

NSDictionary *push = @{

                       @"audience" : @{
                               @"device_token" : deviceToken
                               },
                       @"device_types" : @[ @"ios" ],
                       @"notification" : @{
                               @"ios" : @{
                                       @"alert":Message,
                                       @"sound":@"default",
                                       @"badge":@"auto",
                                       }
                               },
                       @"message": @{
                               @"title": Message,
                               @"body": @"<html><body><h1>blah blah</h1> etc...</html>",
                               @"content_type": @"text/html",
                               @"extra": @{
                                       @"offer_id" : @"608f1f6c-8860-c617-a803-b187b491568e"
                                       }
                               }
                       };


NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", appKey, appMasterSecret];
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed]];
[request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];


NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:push
                                                   options:0 // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                     error:NULL];

request.HTTPBody = jsonData;

[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

}

And The Response:

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *) response {
NSHTTPURLResponse * res = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
NSLog(@"response: %@",res);
NSLog(@"res %li\n",(long)res.statusCode);

if (res.statusCode == 202) {

    //Show Alert Message Sent

}else{

    //Handle Error

}
```

}