# Send PUSH via Urban Airship iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I'm trying to send a PUSH via Urban Airship using code in my app.

I can't seem to find any solid documentation on how to do this. I've tried approaches from other posts here on StackOverflow, this one being the most promising: [how to send push from iphone via urban airship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800382/how-to-send-push-from-iphone-via-urban-airship)

However, following the approach in that post I am getting a 401 error **(401 Unauthorized – The authorization credentials are incorrect)**

For the auth, I am using the **App Key** and **App Secret**. I read on a c# board, that using the **App Master Secret** as the password will work as expected.

When I tried that approach, I received a 400 error: **400 Bad Request – The request body was invalid, either due to malformed JSON or a data validation error. See the response body for more detail.**

Answer (score 1):

The link uses the old push api. Check out docs on the [Push API v3](http://docs.urbanairship.com/api/overview.html).

However we don't recommend storing or using the master secret directly in the app for security reasons. Instead you should have your app authenticate with a server, then have the server send the push for the device.

Comment: That post actually uses the latest (version 3) if you scroll to the bottom. That is what I am working with at the current time.

Comment: The response body will tell you where the error is. Without posting the request body I am unable to help.

Comment: The error is 401 (as mentioned in my original post). Here is the request body: status code: 401, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 54;
    "Content-Type" = "application/vnd.urbanairship+json;version=3";
    Date = "Tue, 17 May 2016 17:06:45 GMT";
    "Www-Authenticate" = "Basic realm=\"API\"";