# Proper way to set basic authentication in NSMutableURLRequest?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa

I want to set basic authentication in my `NSMutableURLRequest`. Currently I am doing this by base64 encrypting my authentication details and using `setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:` (as suggested in many other questions) which works fine. However The documentation for this method and the similar methods says:

> The NSURLConnection class and NSURLSession classes are designed to handle various aspects of the HTTP protocol for you. As a result, you should not modify the following headers:
>
> Authorization
>
> Connection
>
> Host
>
> WWW-Authenticate

Is there a proper way to do Authorization in the http header, or can you only respond to authentication challenges (without ignoring the documentation)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSURLConnection and Basic HTTP Authentication in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973325/nsurlconnection-and-basic-http-authentication-in-ios)

Comment: Other than this question is specifically asking for a solution (if one exists) that doesn't go against the documentation. I've already pointed out that I've used a similar solution to the one in the question pointed at.