# Google OAuth HTTP API iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, oauth, uiwebview

I am trying to get Google OAuth working on iOS so I can make requests to the Google Calendar API. I am currently using this code to load a Google login sheet into a UIWebView and try to get an access token back..

```
[AISWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar&redirect_uri=%@&response_type=code&client_id=%@",kSharedURI,kClientId]]]];
```

I am managing to get what I think is the access token from a text field that appears here, by parsing the HTML again and again using NSString. But when I attempt to use what I think is the access token to make this calendar request using NSMutableURLRequest, I get a response from Google saying

```
 error = {
      code = 401;
      errors =  (
                  {
            domain = global;
            location = Authorization;
            locationType = header;
            message = "Login Required";
            reason = required;
        }
    );
    message = "Login Required";
};
```

If anyone has any ideas they would be absolutely appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you url-encoding the kSharedURI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all please note that I'm not familiar with Google's API.

I think you're sending the OAuth data as parameters in the request. But they request them as an Authentication Header. You should use a framework like NSURLConnection (or 3rd party frameworks) to add those headers.

Refer to this: [NSURLConnection and Basic HTTP Authentication in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973325/nsurlconnection-and-basic-http-authentication-in-ios) for an example

Good luck