# Soap http Request for iOS objective c Error CFURLErrorAuthFailedResponseKey Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Advance thanks,
  I am trying soap request from last 3 days i did all the way finally i come with this sol: 
 Soap response i am getting

```
   UserInfo={_kCFURLErrorAuthFailedResponseKey=<CFURLResponse 0x6000002e8780 [0x10af95df0]>{url = http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxx/xxx/xx/CLF%20Distribution%20Live/Codeunit/WarehouseManagement}
```

i try:

NSString *theUserName = @"xxxxx";

```
NSString *thePassword = @"xxxxx";
NSString *theDomain = @"xxxxx";
```

NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Xml"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxx/xx/xx/xx"];

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];

 [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
 [theRequest addValue:@"urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/WarehouseManagement:GfncValidatePassword" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
 [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
 [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];
[theRequest setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

NSData *webData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

Comment: You missing the creation of `authStr`!

Comment: Here is how you have to prepare HTTP Header Field: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973325/nsurlconnection-and-basic-http-authentication-in-ios

Comment: thanks Lot  – Nazir i try that not usefull

Comment: Thanks  – Libin Varghese authStr i created thats Not i my case i try with this NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];  Error: status code: 401, headers { Connection = close; "Content-Length" = 0; Date = "Tue, 21 Mar 2017 18:39:51 GMT"; Server = "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0"; "Www-Authenticate" = Negotiate;

Comment: i have doubts  in this line NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@:%@", theUserName, thePassword,theDomain];  -  sorry i forgot to this this line above code

Comment: got solution for this problem  I am not change anything in my code server side changes are made I told then to update here.... this may help please check your api  in postman...