# Why this POST don't work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection, http-post, nsmutableurlrequest

this is my snippet:

```
NSString *post = @"from=A&name=B&email=ciccio@aaasd.com&messaggio=MESSAGE&codHidden=-1";
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];    

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/page.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData]; 

NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[urlData length]);
NSString *outputdata = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", outputdata);
```

It call a php page that send me an email...

Is there any errors in this code?
Does not seem to work...

thanks

Comment: We would need the contents of the PHP script as well. There could be a problem there.

Comment: Ok. The objc code works about you?

Comment: What gets logged from the `NSLog()` functions?

Comment: nothing. the page doesn't return a value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a Synchronous/Asynchronous problem? If so, use the delegate-pattern and access the data asynchronously. Could you post any errors you see (or the server's response string)?

EDIT: Since you're not doing anything useful with the error returned, change your class to do the request *asynchronously*. A great answer to this was previously posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993409/basic-http-authentication-on-iphone/993421#993421). Once you implement `didFailWithError` you'll have a better picture.

Comment: No error, no response (because the page return an empty string), and no mail! The code is correct? If yes, I have to order change/fix the php page...

Comment: Well, firstly, you're not sending your NSError response to an object you can investigate after the method returns. So, change the above to

`NSError *returnedError;
NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&returnedError];`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change NSASCIIStringEncoding  to  NSUTF8StringEncoding